# Function preg_match() for end of string matching

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to check whether the last characters of `$url` are one of the following:

`.gif` `.png` `.bmp` `.jpg` `.jpeg`

It works fine for one of them:

```php
if(!preg_match('/\.jpg$/', $url))
```

but putting them all together isn't working:

```php
if(!preg_match('/[\.gif$\.png$\.bmp$\.jpg$\.jpeg$]/', $url))`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "`!`" part [may or may not be reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254239/preg-match-if-not/6254296#6254296) (for instance, false positives or false negatives). That is, even with the correct regular expression, it may still not behave as expected.

Comment: Or in other words, an explicit `!== 0` (compare to ***integer***) for testing for ***regular expression (string) match*** (not `!== false` (Boolean)). Yes, this goes against the advice for other languages, but not following it in this case may result in a lot of hairpulling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using a character class when you want alternation...

```
"/\.(gif|png|bmp|jpe?g)$/"
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot place "strings" inside a character class. Character classes work with **characters**, not strings. A character class can **match only one out of several characters.**

So, the following regex:

```
/[\.gif$\.png$\.bmp$\.jpg$\.jpeg$]/
```

matches a single character from the character list between `[` and `]`. Also, remember that the dot is not a metacharacter inside a character class, so you don't need `\.` - just `.` will suffice, but it doesn't matter anyway because this is a wrong approach.

**Visual representation:**

[image: match]

Use alteration to achieve what you want. For example, `(foo|bar)` matches `foo` **or** `bar`. For your requirements, the following regular expression might work:

```
/\.(gif|png|bmp|jpe?g)$/
```

Although, I would not use a regex for this. There's already a function that was built for the exact purpose -- to determine the extension of a file (or URL):

```
$ext = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```